# Callback function for DistanceMatrix API

Tags: java, google-maps

I am using the Google Distance Matrix API to compute distance between different lat longs. I am calling the respective API as mentioned below

```
public void computeDistanceAndTime() 
{    
        try 
        {
            DistanceMatrixApiRequest req =     DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(Context.getContext()).origins(src)
                    .destinations(dst).mode(TravelMode.WALKING);
                DistanceMatrix matrix = req.await();
        }
        catch (OverQueryLimitException o) 
        {
            System.out.println(o.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Actually I want to set a callback using `setCallback` function `DistanceMatrixApiRequest`. So I am assuming rather catching the excepetion  the callback would be get called and could avoid the

> com.google.maps.internal.OkHttpPendingResult retry

exception from google. 
Now I am not aware how to set the callback like

1. what is the signature of the call back?
2. Do we need to inherit any class to set the callback
3. What would be the parameters of that function?
4. I am assuming that needs to called before calling the await function, am I correct?

I could see one example for Geocoding as like below,

```
req.setCallback(new PendingResult.Callback<GeocodingResult[]>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(GeocodingResult[] result) {
    // Handle successful request.
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
    // Handle error.
  }
});
```

I am not successfull even if I follow in similar manner for Distance Matrix.

```
 req.setCallback(new PendingResult.Callback<DistanceMatrix[]>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(DistanceMatrix[] result) {
    // Handle successful request.
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("There is a failure in Distance function");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using `DistanceMatrixApi` with a callback instead of `await()`. Note, I need to use a `CountDownLatch` due to OkHTTP invoking the callback on a background thread.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.maps.DistanceMatrixApi;
import com.google.maps.DistanceMatrixApiRequest;
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;
import com.google.maps.PendingResult;
import com.google.maps.model.DistanceMatrix;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class DistanceMatrixApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext();
    context.setApiKey("[API KEY]");
    DistanceMatrixApiRequest req = DistanceMatrixApi.getDistanceMatrix(context,
    new String[]{"Sydney Town Hall"},
    new String[]{"Parramatta Station"});

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    req.setCallback(new PendingResult.Callback<DistanceMatrix>() {
      @Override
      public void onResult(DistanceMatrix result) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(result));
        latch.countDown();
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown: "+e);
        latch.countDown();
      }
    });

    // We have to hold the main thread open until callback is called by OkHTTP.
    latch.await();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brett, for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Brett, I wrote the function in the similar line as mentioned above but not able to get the callback on the onFailure function. So I am using the OverQueryLimitException to catch this exception.